# Como atualizar forms no Django

Tags: python, django

Olá, pessoal. É o seguinte: tenho dois forms que se integram com um model no Django, sendo eles:

**forms.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
from django import forms
from .models import CadastroModel

class CadastroForm(forms.Form):
    nome = forms.CharField(label="Nome", max_length=200)


class AddPontoForm(forms.Form):    
    tipos = [(0, 'Selecione'), (1, 'Entrada'), (2, 'Intervalo'), (3, 'Retorno'), (4, 'Saida'),]
    nomes_cad = CadastroModel.objects.all()
    nomes = []
    i = 0
    for n in nomes_cad:
        nomes.append((i, n.nome))
        i += 1
    nome = forms.ChoiceField(label="Nome", choices=nomes)
    dia = forms.DateField(label="Dia", initial=datetime.today())
    tipo = forms.ChoiceField(label="Marcacao", choices=tipos)
    hora = forms.CharField(label="Hora", max_length=200)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class CadastroModel(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str___(self):
        return self.nome
```

**views.py**

```
def cadastro(request):
    form = CadastroForm(request.POST or None)
    if str(request.method) == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            nome = form.cleaned_data['nome']
            novo_func = CadastroModel(nome=nome)
            novo_func.save()
            messages.success(request, "Funcionario(a) cadastrado(a) com sucesso!")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Falha no cadastro!")
```

Ou seja, uso os dados inseridos no formulário CadastroForm para inserir nomes no banco de dados. O problema é que no form AddPontoForm, no campo `nome`, é realizado uma busca no db que **deveria** retornar os nomes cadastrados. Porém, quando insiro os nomes em CadastroForm, eles são salvos corretamente, mas não atualizam a listagem de nomes no formulário AddPontoForm, mesmo que eu recarregue a página, feche e a abra novamente. Eu preciso parar o servidor, e iniciá-lo novamente para que a listagem apareça atualizada.

Como posso fazer para que assim que um adicione um novo nome no banco de dados ele já apareça na listagem de nomes do outro formulário?

Comment: Oi, não está faltando um dos teus models? A tua função na views.py está completa?

Comment: Sim, eu tenho outros form/model que tem os mesmos campos (nome, data, tipo e hora) e outra view que renderiza esse outro form e insere esses dados no db. Mas relacionada a minha dúvida, é apenas a questão do campo 'nome' que não atualiza no form AddPontoForm quando insiro um novo funcionário. É como se o ` nomes_cad = CadastroModel.objects.all()` deixasse de funcionar corretamente e não retorna a busca completa no banco de dados com os novos registros no model CadastroModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nathan, quando você faz o carregamento dos dados dessa maneira

```
class AddPontoForm(forms.Form):    
    tipos = [(0, 'Selecione'), (1, 'Entrada'), (2, 'Intervalo'), (3, 'Retorno'), (4, 'Saida'),]
    nomes_cad = CadastroModel.objects.all()
    nomes = []
    i = 0
    for n in nomes_cad:
        nomes.append((i, n.nome))
        i += 1
    nome = forms.ChoiceField(label="Nome", choices=nomes)
```

Você está na verdade carregando os dados no momento em que o Django é iniciado. Sendo assim, você não recarregará os dados a cada requisição que é feita. Se quiser fazer um teste, adicione um novo `CadastroModel` e reinicie o servidor do Django. O dado irá aparecer na listagem.

Porém existe na documentação do Django um cara chamado [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) que é responsável por fazer o carregamento das opções de acordo com um queryset. Que acredito que é o que você está procurando.

```
class AddPontoForm(forms.Form):    
    tipos = [(0, 'Selecione'), (1, 'Entrada'), (2, 'Intervalo'), (3, 'Retorno'), (4, 'Saida'),]
    nome = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Nome", queryset=CadastroModel.objects.all())
    dia = forms.DateField(label="Dia", initial=datetime.today())
    tipo = forms.ChoiceField(label="Marcacao", choices=tipos)
    hora = forms.CharField(label="Hora", max_length=200)
```